# In Trello, can two cards be on the list at the same position?

Tags: trello

We would like to have two cards on the same list in the same position.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. A card can only occupy one spot at once. Perhaps consider tagging the cards uniquely to denote equal priority?